# In Bixby how do I enable the user to page through a series of results in sequence?

Tags: bixby

I have a table of contents type structure of articles that I want the user to read before they take a survey.  How can I work this out? It doesn't seem exactly like a normal result-view.

E.g:

```
Introduction
What Is Bixby?
Making Money
Key Features 
... 
Sign up
```

Comment: What sort of conversation flow are you envisioning? Do you have a script?

Answer (score 4):

You can have an action that returns and array of those results.  Possibly create a structure that contains the following:

```
[{
Title: 'Intro',
Description: 'Intro Description',
ResultType: 'Intro"
},
// More results
]
```

In your result view, you can use **navigation-mode** and set it to read-one with the page-size as 1.  This will allow you to flow through the array on the screen in order.  You may need to check the 'ResultType' from the array to determine which elements are displayed for each view.

More information [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.render.list-of.navigation-mode):

Comment: Helpful as always. Thanks!